# What can we eat and what we can't eat during Mother Lakshmi's fast?

Tags: food, lakshmi, fasting, vrata

I have searched and heard too from many people but some say that we cannot eat salty food but some say we can. Confusion became even more because Friday is for both Mother Lakshmi and Mother Santoshi.

And both might have different instructions related to meal consumption. Even in Vaibhava Lakshmi's vrata katha, nowhere is mentioned about what we should eat.

So, is there any scripture or any hindu text that tells us about what we should or should not eat in Vaibhava Lakshmi's fast?

Comment: Irrespective of what fast it is the moment you take salt the fast is broken..

Comment: @rickross Every fasts has different rules. Some fasts allows to eat salt, e.g. Navratra, SatyaNarayana etc.

Comment: Btw rocksalt is allowed in fasts .. are you talking about that?

Comment: @rickross I don't know what rocksalt is. But I have seen every person eating aaloo sabji in Navratra fasts. How alloo sabji can be cooked without salt? This means they all did break their Navratra fasts on day one since they ate salt in aloo sabji?

Comment: Yes they use rocksalt in the preparation .. it is reddish in color and that is allowed in fasts .. white salt is prohibited .. In Bengal we call that red salt Saindhav lavan ... pls search on Google (In Hindi its probably called Sendha namak)

Comment: @rickross You are scaring me now.... I am doing Satya Narayana fasts since more than a year and I always use to eat meal prepared with white salt. I don't know about this... I am numb right now.

Comment: Well this is what I know ... the red salt is allowed to be consumed during fasts and not the usual white salt we use daily .. Pls search on Google "Sendha namak Navaratri" .. you will get some results

Comment: Although I am not recommending that site Quora but you can see this: https://www.quora.com/Why-is-rock-salt-allowed-and-table-salt-not-allowed-during-navratri-fast